# If I declare a fragment in an XML layout, how do I pass it a Bundle?

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment

I've got an activity that I've replaced with a fragment.  The activity took an Intent that had some extra information on what data the activity was supposed to display.

Now that my Activity is just a wrapper around a Fragment that does the same work, how do I get that bundle to the Fragment if I declare the fragment in XML with the  tag?

If I were to use a FragmentTransaction to put the Fragment into a ViewGroup, I'd get a chance to pass this info along in the Fragment constructor, but I'm wondering about the situation where the fragment is defined in XML.

Comment: Try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641575/custom-attributes-in-android-fragments/17674292#17674292

Comment: its dead easy, see the excellent answer of @DanieleSegato

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> Now that my Activity is just a wrapper around a Fragment that does the same work, how do I get that bundle to the Fragment if I declare the fragment in XML with the tag?

You can't.

However, you are welcome to call `findFragmentById()` on your `FragmentManager` to retrieve the fragment post-inflation, then call some method on the fragment to associate data with it. While apparently that cannot be `setArguments()`, your fragment could arrange to hold onto the data itself past a configuration change by some other means (`onSaveInstanceState()`, `setRetainInstance(true)`, etc.).

Comment: When I asked this question, I decided to go a different route.  But just today, I had a similar situation, and came back to this post.  I thought I'd give it a try.  The setArguments solution doesn't seem to work:  
10-24 12:48:33.276: E/AndroidRuntime(21417): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active  
Going to try just calling a method on the Fragment.

Comment: I ran into the same IllegalStateException the other day. The problem seems to be that you need to call `setContentView()` in order for the Fragments to be inflated. But `setContentView()` also attaches them to the Activity which makes it too late to call `setArguments()`.

Comment: This should not be marked as correct. It is incorrect. According to the fragment documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle), setArguments() must be called before the fragment has been attached to the activity. If you can find the fragment via findFragmentById() then the fragment has already been attached. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403040/android-fragment-declared-in-layout-how-to-set-arguments?lq=1 for the correct solution.

Comment: @Neil: I can understand the source of your confusion. I have made a small edit to clarify the timing of the `setArguments()` call.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm still not sure if that's correct. Your edit says "do this before executing the FragmentTransaction" which isn't applicable here because the fragment is declared in an XML layout and there is no fragment instance to interact with.

Comment: @Neil: You are correct, insofar as my edit was wrong. Remind me never to make an edit to an answer from my phone. However, your linked-to answer is irrelevant, as it too does not address fragment inflation, other than to say that you can't use it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124150/set-arguments-of-fragment-from-activity for options on how to pass data to an XML defined Fragment.

Comment: To resolve the issues with `setArguments()`, you **could** `@Override` it in your `Fragment` subclass. Deal with the arguments directly and don't chain to `super`. Now no more `IllegalStateException`. Of course, writing your own method and casting to your subclass to call it is also a decent solution.

Comment: You are right, you cannot pass a bundle, but you're answer is missleading cause what people usually want is just pass values to their fragments. I added an answer showing how to do so via attributes

Answer (score 50):

It's not an encapsulated way, but I ended up "pulling" the bundle from the parent activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
```

Answer (score 26):

You can't pass a Bundle (unless you inflate your fragment programmatically rather then via XML) but you CAN pass parameters (or rather attributes) via XML to a fragment.

The process is similar to [how you define View custom attributes](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr).
Except AndroidStudio (currently) do not assist you in the process.

suppose this is your fragment using arguments (I'll use kotlin but it totally works in Java too):

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {

    // your fragment parameter, a string
    private var screenName: String? = null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (screenName == null) {
            screenName = arguments?.getString("screen_name")
        }
    }
}
```

And you want to do something like this:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myFragment"
    android:name="com.example.MyFragment"
    app:screen_name="@string/screen_a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Note the `app:screen_name="@string/screen_a"`

to make it work just add this in a values file (`fragment_attrs.xml` or pick any name you want):

```
<!-- define your attribute name and type -->
<attr name="screen_name" format="string|reference"/>

<!-- define a bunch of constants you wanna use -->
<string name="screen_a" translatable="false">ScreenA</string>
<string name="screen_b" translatable="false">ScreeenB</string>

<!-- now define which arguments your fragment is gonna have (can be more then one) -->
<!-- the convention is "FragmentClassName_MembersInjector" -->
<declare-styleable name="MyFragment_MembersInjector">
    <attr name="screen_name"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Almost done, you just need to read it in your fragment, so add the method:

```
override fun onInflate(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onInflate(context, attrs, savedInstanceState)
    if (context != null && attrs != null && screenName == null) {
        val ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyFragment_MembersInjector)
        if (ta.hasValue(R.styleable.MyFragment_MembersInjector_screen_name)) {
            screenName = ta.getString(R.styleable.MyFragment_MembersInjector_screen_name)
        }
        ta.recycle()
    }
}
```

et voilá, your XML attributes in your fragment :)

Limitations:

- Android Studio (as of now) do not autocomplete such arguments in the layout XML
- You can't pass `Parcelable` but only what can be defined as Android Attributes

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Saviour, just what i was looking for.

Comment: Wow.  10 years Android programming and I never though of this. I just hope that I will not abuse this hahah because it's really nifty

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to not declare the fragment in the XML. I know it is not exactly what you want to do. However you could declare a simple layout in your view like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

And then in your `Activity` class you programatically inflate the layout with the fragment. This way you can pass through parameters using args.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
MyFragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(Global.INTENT_INT_ROLE, 1);
fragment.setArguments(args);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "MyActivity");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

In the fragment,

```
if (getArguments() != null) {
   int role = getArguments().getInt(Global.INTENT_INT_ROLE); }
```

This approach is not as clean and simple as declaring it in the xml however I have moved to it as it gives you a lot more control over the fragment.

Comment: This is a bit of a "then don't do that" approach, however it makes more sense to me than the idea of exchanging data via singleton objects (as another answer suggests)

Comment: If the singleton objects are not backed by a persisting database, then Android can destroy your apps process in the background and try to recreate its former state later from the fragment arguments or the bundle. Singletons wont get restored and app state will be lost, this leads to bad UX - try to avoid doing that by either using fragment arguments or backing your singletons up by a database.

Comment: Your answers ARE SO HELPFUL !!!!!!!!! WHAAAAAA ! https://tenor.com/search/thank-you-anime-gifs

Comment: @A.Steenbergen sure, but a common situation is if the agrs don't exist, perform some default; if they do exist use that.

Answer (score 9):

I know its too late answer, but i think someone need that :)

Just in activity override `onAttachFragment()`

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

    if (fragment.getId() == R.id.frgBlank)
    {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", "Message");

        fragment.setArguments(b);
    }
}
```

and in fragment onCreateView method

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
if (b != null)
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), b.getString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I see is to not use the arguments as data exchange channel. Instead, make your fragment to obtain the necessary information from elsewhere. Call back to get the proper activity, consult a temporary storage memory, a Singleton object, etc..

Another solution that can be helpful is to employ frameworks that allow unrelated objects to exchange messages via Mediator design pattern, as [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).

Answer (score 0):

this approach worked for me.

You will not pass the Bundle from Anywhere, but instead you can set the arguments in onAttach method in the fragment itself.

and later in the lifecycle methods of the fragments you can use those bundle arguments.

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if(arguments == null){
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("mykey", "myvalue")
            arguments = bundle
        }
    }
```

Anyone might ask a question, why to set the arguments in the fragment while we can directly use the values in the usable places. It's right, but
This approach can also work when you will be passing these arguments to some other classes let's say any view model.

for example

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        /*
         Here I am passing these arguments to a viewmodel 
        */
        viewModel.prepareData(arguments) 
        
        --------
        --------
        --------

    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since [v1.3.0 of the androidx.fragment](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0) module (Feb 2021), they deprecated the `onAttachFragment()` callbacks in favor of using a [FragmentOnAttachListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentOnAttachListener), which is attached to your [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#addFragmentOnAttachListener(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentOnAttachListener)). So inside your `FragmentActivity`'s `onCreate`, you could do something like:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addFragmentOnAttachListener((fragmentManager, fragment) -> {
    if (fragment instanceof MyFragment) {
        Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
    }
}
```

This will fire after `setContentView()` if you use `<fragment>` in your XML, but happens later if you used a `<FragmentContainerView>`.

Be careful, [as I've noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73585265/954643) that a configuration change could re-attach an existing Fragment inside `super.onCreate`, and therefore needed to add the listener *before* this point. (That said, this isn't necessary for the purpose of passing `Bundle` args, and otherwise one should try to use [onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) first.)

---

Incidentally, listening for the "onAttach" could also be a handy place to add an observer of the Fragment's view [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#states) if needed, should you need to do anything in the Activity once the Fragment's view is instantiated. e.g. add:

```
        LiveData<LifecycleOwner> liveData = fragment.getViewLifecycleOwnerLiveData();
        // Let this observer be constrained to the fragment's lifecycle.
        liveData.observe(fragment, new Observer<LifecycleOwner>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
                // ...do work...
                // If you don't need to listen anymore, can clean ourselves up early.
                liveData.removeObserver(this);
            }
        });
```

Or as an alternative to observing the Fragment's view lifecycle from the Activity (and as a replacement for the Fragment's deprecated [onActivityCreated()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle))), you can listen the other way, to the Activity's Lifecycle from the Fragment! From the Fragment's [onAttach(context)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onAttach(android.content.Context)) callback, add your own [observer](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/DefaultLifecycleObserver) that implements [onCreate(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/DefaultLifecycleObserver#onCreate(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner)). re: [onActivityCreated is deprecated, how to properly use LifecycleObserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61306719/onactivitycreated-is-deprecated-how-to-properly-use-lifecycleobserver)