# Android Fragment declared in layout, how to set arguments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got a fragment that uses getArguments() method in onCreateView, to get some input data.

I'm using this fragment with ViewPager and it works fine.

The problem starts when I try to reuse this fragment in a different activity, that shows this fragment only. I wanted to add the fragment to the activitie's layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.ScheduleDayFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

The question is: how to pass a Bundle to a fragment declared in layout?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034746/if-i-declare-a-fragment-in-an-xml-layout-how-do-i-pass-it-a-bundle

Comment: Thanks, it seems that it is not possible.

Comment: why you need to do that ?

Comment: I wanted to reuse a Fragment that uses a Bundle to show appropriate content

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way would be to change the  to FrameLayout and put the fragment in code.

```
public void onCreate(...) {

    ScheduleDayFragment fragment = new ScheduleDayFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.main_view, fragment).commit();
    ...
}
```

Here is the layout file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Are you worried this is going to reduce performance somehow?

Comment: I ended up with this solution. I was trying to find something more elegant, but apparently it is not possible.

Answer (score 6):

i know its too late answer, but i think someone need that :)

### just in activity override onAttachFragment()

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment)
{
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

    if (fragment.getId() == R.id.frgBlank)
    {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", "Message");

        fragment.setArguments(b);
    }
}
```

### and in fragment onCreateView method

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
if (b != null)
{
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), b.getString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

### just like that, hope to help someone :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are stick with the fragment declaration within your layout, you can use this check within your Fragment.OnCreateView()

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // value can be restored after Fragment is restored
        value = savedInstanceState.getInt("myValueTag", -1);

    } else if (getArguments() != null) {
        // value is set by Fragment arguments
        value = getArguments().getInt("myValueTag", -1);

    } else if (getActivity() != null && getActivity().getIntent() != null) {
        // value is read from activity intent
        value = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("myValueTag", -1);
    }
```

finally just add your value information to the intent created for startActivity() call