# Passing argument to fragment that is defined in XML layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);
    }
}
```

**activity_one.xml**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    class="com.emoontech.waternow.FragmentA"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**FragmentA**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment{
    public static FragmentEditEvent newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentEditEvent fragment = new FragmentEditEvent();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

//From Another Activity on button click

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.putString("param1","val1");
intent.putString("param2","val2");
startActivity(intent);
```

//How to send these two values to FragmentA?

Comment: Check this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16036693/4636437) question is similar

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass values between Fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)

Comment: I already looked into it.  Do you say that, i cant  use <fragment > in activity_main.xml? do i have to create the fragment instance inside the onCreate() of activity and pass arguments?

Answer (score 3):

answer i made there https://stackoverflow.com/a/32748751/3301009 to share data between activities is very general and can also work for fragments

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
        // From ActivityA
        // retrieve the content of the intent from the previous activity
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment); // set content view to layout

        String param1Text= getIntent().getStringExtra("param1");
        String param2Text = getIntent().getStringExtra("param2");

        // this will pass the parameter to the fragment
        Fragment frament = FragmentA.newInstance(param1Text, param2Text);
        // use the fragment for what you desire

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found that its not possible to pass argument to the faragment directly but alternative is to use fragment manager and do findFragmentById() in activity to get fragment and set the date as needed.

Edit:
[If I declare a fragment in an XML layout, how do I pass it a Bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034746/if-i-declare-a-fragment-in-an-xml-layout-how-do-i-pass-it-a-bundle)