# Parcelable from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, parcelable

I am new to parcelable and I am trying to pass data from an Activity (MainActivity) to a fragment (MainFragment) but I`m struggle to get this right.

I made a class (InfoBean) with all the (parcelable) data. When I **send the data from the MainActivity**, the data from bean.newTheme (**2131296447**) is there but as soon as I try to **retrieve in the Fragment**, the value is **0**!

Could someone pls have a look, what I`m doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Send data (MainActivity):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    InfoBean bean = new InfoBean();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  SecureSharedPreferences theme = SecureSharedPreferences.getInstance(this, "MyPrefsFile");

        int newTheme = theme.getInt("themeCustom", 0);
        bean.newTheme = newTheme;

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("theme", bean.newTheme); // debug shows value 2131296447 
        MainFragment mf = new MainFragment();
        mf.setArguments(bundle); 
    //
  }
}
```

Retrieve data (MainFragment):

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

  InfoBean bean = new InfoBean();

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   //
   Bundle bundle = this.getArguments(); // Debugging shows 0!
     if (bundle != null) {
         bean.newTheme = bundle.getInt("theme");
        }

     if (bean.newTheme == 2131296447) { // White Theme
         mCardView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E8EBED"));
        } else { // Dark Theme
         mCardView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#282929"));
         relLay.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1B1C1C"));
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

InfoBean.class:

```
public class InfoBean implements Parcelable {

    public int newTheme;
    public int THEME_DARK = R.style.DarkTheme;
    public int THEME_LIGHT = R.style.LightTheme;

@Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.newTheme);
        dest.writeInt(this.THEME_DARK);
        dest.writeInt(this.THEME_LIGHT);

}

    public InfoBean() {
    }

    protected InfoBean(Parcel in) {
        this.newTheme = in.readInt();
        this.THEME_DARK = in.readInt();
        this.THEME_LIGHT = in.readInt();

}

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<InfoBean> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<InfoBean>() {
        @Override
        public InfoBean createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new InfoBean(source);
        }

        @Override
        public InfoBean[] newArray(int size) {
            return new InfoBean[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: is your fragment embedded in xml or you are dynamically creating it?

Comment: @Pooya it`s embedded in xml

Comment: You can't pass values that is embedbed in xml. duh

Comment: as far as I can see you're only passing an `int` in this Bean. If that is the case you should pass just that `putInt` to the fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have embedded fragment in your XML you can't use the `setArguments()` like that in your program. It is better to use dynamic fragment creation.

There is a brief example in android developer website which can guide you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html there is also another implementation when you have embedded fragments and how to process arguments with that.

There is also another resource here which may help you:

[Set arguments of fragment from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124150/set-arguments-of-fragment-from-activity)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Since you have your fragment embedded in xml, you can't pass values to fragment class. To that you need to make it excute through java code and remove that xml. Make fragment Transaction then it will work

**Update**

You should try retrieving values in onCreate method of fragment.

```
@overide
protect void onCreate(bundle onSavedInstance){
   if (savedInstance != null) {
     bean.newTheme = bundle.getInt("theme");
    }
}
```

Try this

```
 if (bundle != null) {
         bean.newTheme = bundle.getInt("theme");
        }
```

instead of

```
 if (bundle != null) {
         bean.newTheme = bundle.getParcelable("theme");
        }
```

Comment: thx for replying. If I do that, value is still 0.
bean.newTheme = bundle.getInt("theme");

Comment: Weird, Bundle bundle = this.getArguments(); gives 0. So nothing there.
I don`t see the mistake.

Comment: Updated my answer. You should overide onCreate method and try to retrieve value from there

Comment: I am sorry, still a no go and I thought parcelables were easy ;)

Comment: I think problem is with your InfoBean class why does describeContents() returns 0?

Comment: bean.newTheme is indeed 0 in the Fragment but in the MainActivity it has the value (2131296447) I need and I also pass it through (bundle.putInt("theme", bean.newTheme). So I don`t understand.
I though I just could retrive it by calling bean.newTheme but I am wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108023/discussion-between-zeeshan-shabbir-and-simon).

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, you are using .putInt("theme" .....) but in the fragment you call .getParcelable("theme").  You're getting 0 because you're attempting to get two different data types.

Comment: thx for the answer. If I change that to 'getInt' value is till 0.
Code edited.