# Supplying custom attribute values to a dynamically created Android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I understand how to define custom attributes for a fragment and specify their values in XML (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674292/67316)). But I'm not sure how to do this for fragments that are *dynamically* created in `Activity.onCreate()`. How do I provide the attribute values so that the fragment can get them by calling `Context.obtainStyledAttributes()` in its `onInflate()`?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I provide the attribute values

You need to make your fragment handling arguments (see [setArguments()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle))) and then pass whatever you need to your newly created Fragment object, overriding XML or framgent defaults.

Comment: Hi Marcin. I understand how to do that (and its my current workaround) but using the arguments means that, if I want to the fragment to work if its created statically in xml or dynamically, I need to implement the attribute value handling twice. This doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: You can create separate setter methods for each attribute handled and pass data either from XML attributes of bundle to is for handling so you will have still one implementation.

Comment: `the attribute value handling twice` Using arguments is the only proper way as this deals with fragment reinstantiation automatically

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
@Override
    public void onInflate(Activity activity, AttributeSet attrs, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onInflate(activity, attrs, savedInstanceState); 
        // Your code here to process the attributes
    }
```