# BindingAdapter for fragment

Tags: attributes, fragment, adapter

In my main activity layout xml, I have a fragment tag. 
I would like to create a custom attribute  , say app:myCustomAttribute (see below), in the tag using @BindingAdapter. Is this even possible? I can't find a solution online.  If not possible, is there any simple way to create a custom attribute in fragment. Someone posts a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641575/custom-attributes-in-android-fragments), but the solution seems quite cumberson, and still need to define an attrs.xml in the resource folder.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_createTaskForm"
        android:name="com.edenhan.simplytask.CreateTaskForm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="191dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_create_task_form"
        app:myCustomAttribute="test"
        />
```